# What impacts does RTT have on the behaviour of TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp

How does round-trip time impact a TCP connection's behaviour? I know that the throughput of a connection with a high RTT is lower than the throughput of a connection with a low RTT but how does RTT impact the way TCP behave (congestion control, amount of packages sent, how we acknowledge packets)?

Lets say we're past slow-start and in the congestion avoidance phase. Does RTT influence the amount of data we have "in flight"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure does. You've discovered the [Bandwidth Delay Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product).